# VBA MS ACCESS how to open files created on certain time frame?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have multiple CSV files that need to be opened and if possible all imported into a single table...
The criteria is the creation dates i.e. open files created between a chosen date span.
Bellow is the test code borrowed from other posts and tweaked it a bit ,but run into code issues and can't get pass the error(s):
**Edit: if there is a better/faster way to accomplish this task, it will be greatly appreciated as well**
Updated code below, NO errors generated; however, nothing is happening at all, no table being created, no files being imported...
Thank you so much for your help

```
Dim oFile
Dim FSO As Object 'FileSystemObject
Set oFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Directory As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim varCellvalue As Long

Directory = "E:\Op60\"
If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
   Directory = Directory & "\"
End If

FileName = Dir(Directory & "*.CSV")

''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim DateEarliest As Date
Dim EarliestDate As Date

EarliestDate = txt_Start_Date
DateEarliest = CDate(EarliestDate)

Dim DateLatest As Date
Dim LatestDate As Date

LatestDate = txt_Start_Date2
DateLatest = CDate(LatestDate)

 Do While FileName <> ""
 '**-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
 'Debug.Print oFile.getFile(Directory & FileName).DateCreated, EarliestDate, LatestDate
 '**************
 If oFile.getFile(Directory & FileName).DateCreated >= DateEarliest And oFile.getFile(Directory & FileName).DateCreated <= DateLatest Then
    DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="CsvTbl", FileName:=Directory & FileName, HasFieldNames:=True
End If
 
FileName = Dir

 Loop
```

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating` is for the Excel Application object. Access uses `Application.Echo` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.echo

Comment: For the other error what are the values in `EarliestDate` and `LatestDate` from your assignment I'm guessing they are string types and you can't do arithmetic comparisons between string and date type variables.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a line to *debug* your criteria:

```vb
Debug.Print oFile.getFile(Directory & FileName).DateCreated, EarliestDate, LatestDate
         
if oFile.getFile(Directory & FileName).DateCreated >= EarliestDate and oFile.getFile(Directory & FileName).DateCreated <= LatestDate
<snip>
```

Also, use a proper syntax for `TransferText`:

```vb
If oFile.getFile(Directory & FileName).DateCreated >= DateEarliest And oFile.getFile(Directory & FileName).DateCreated <= DateLatest Then
    DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="CsvTbl", FileName:=Directory & FileName, HasFieldNames:=True
End If
```

Comment: Added the Debug; however, the error still remains "syntax error" at the "if oFile.getFile..." line. the dates come from two text boxes formatted as general date each btw. and there is no debug output to be looked at. thank you for your assistance

Comment: _there is no debug output to be looked at_ ... oh yes, there will be the three values. And, of course, the debug line doesn't correct your syntax, only displays it for you.

Comment: got he following debug output: 9/16/2021 11:50:26 AM 9/17/2021 9/15/2021 9/16/2021 11:50:26 AM 9/17/2021 9/15/2021 9/16/2021 11:50:26 AM 9/17/2021 9/15/2021 .... however, the file open portion of the code is not working at all

Comment: See extended answer, please